# How to make jinternal frame ceter in main frame?

Tags: java, netbeans, jinternalframe

I am working on a java project. I've already created the main frame with desktop pane and several j internal frames. I want to center all j internal frames. 
Can someone give me a suggestion how to center it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Read about [Layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

Comment: @Madhan: AFAIK, LayoutManagers can't be applied to InternalFrames...

Comment: @Marco13 The layout has to be applied to JDesktopPane not to JInternalFrame and it seems we can [apply layouts to it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setLayout(java.awt.LayoutManager))

Comment: What do you mean by center all frames.If everything is in center wont it overlap each other

Comment: yeah it overlaps but i can close previous frame when new frame opens. And i just want to know the process. I am new to java and still learning

Answer (score 1):

Try this logic. I'd done this for only one JInternalFrame.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.Component;

public final class CenterChild extends JFrame{

    private JDesktopPane   contentPane;
    private JInternalFrame child;

    @Override
    public void frameInit(){
        super.frameInit();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(0,0,500,500);
        this.selfInitialize();
    }

    private void selfInitialize(){
        contentPane = new JDesktopPane();
        child       = new JInternalFrame("Centered Child");

        child.setClosable(true);
        child.setVisible(true);

        child.setSize(300,200);
        //Centering the JInternalFrame
        child.setLocation((getWidth() - child.getWidth())/2, (getHeight() - child.getHeight())/2);

        contentPane.add(child);
        this.setContentPane(contentPane);

        addComponentListener(new ResizeEventHandler());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{ new CenterChild();});
    }
    //Code that re positions JInternalFrame while main window size changes
    private class ResizeEventHandler extends ComponentAdapter{
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){
            Component invoker = e.getComponent();
            //re positioning the JInternalFrame to the main window's center
            child.reshape((invoker.getWidth() - child.getWidth())/2, (invoker.getHeight() - child.getHeight())/2,300,200);          
        }
    }
}
```